# Adding icon to shortcut created on desktop for c# application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, icons

I have a Windows C# application and I am creating a setup file for the same.
The problem is that the icon that I give to my shortcut file on user's desktop does not appear when the application is installed.

Please help.

Comment: What do you do in particular?

Comment: Oh well.. I hope this is not related to any coding stuff... Is it ?

Comment: More information needed in order to answer your question. What has C# to do with your question?

Comment: I tried adding an icon file to exe file that we drag and drop to user's desktop.

Comment: c# or visual studio anything may help. I dont know if any coding is required

Comment: HOW did you (try) do that?

Comment: WPF, windows forms, console app? How did you do it?

Comment: how are you deploying your application?

Comment: Are you including the icon as part of the setup and deploy package?

Comment: Yes but what is the exact way to add an icon file to the shortcut or exe file that the setup project creates ?

Comment: @Fred: yes i did that

Comment: @L-Three: Windows forms sir

Comment: And it is in the folder specified in the shortcut properties? Or is it part of the EXE created?

Comment: @Fred: It is the specified folder. basically I tried entering the property tab called icon of the shortcut that is created and set an icon file to it. But it doesnt work